# Why can't *pointer+offset be used as an l-value? ("error: non-lvalue in assignment")

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, syntax

Here is my code:

```
void doubleValuesInArray(int *pointer) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
        int a = (*pointer+n);
        a = a * 2;
        *pointer+n = a;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int myArray[] = {1,2};
    doubleValuesInArray(myArray);
    cout<<myArray[0]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

main.cpp: In function `void doubleValuesInArray(int*)':
main.cpp:19: error: non-lvalue in assignment
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[1]:**  [.build-conf] Error 2
make: ** [.build-impl] Error 2

My question is:

```
int a = (*pointer+n);
```

works just fine. Variable 'a' gets the values 0 and 1 from the array by using *pointer + n.

However

```
 *pointer+n = a;
```

does not seem to work.

If I use 
    pointer[n] = a;
it works as well.

Why doesn't my first approach work?

Comment: Can someone suggest a better title for this question so it can appear in searches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not parenthesize your pointer expressions correctly: the `*` has higher priority, so you should add parentheses around the addition:

```
int a = *(pointer+n);
a = a * 2;
*(pointer+n) = a;
```

Comment: @nos Using the `[]` operator is definitely cleaner, and that is definitely what I would do in my code. However, I think the OP wanted to know specifically about dereferencing a sum of a pointer and an index, rather than using the less exotic `[]` option.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite clear - `*pointer+n` is an r-value - meaning you can't assign to it.

Did you mean

```
*(pointer+n) = a;
```

because the two are different. `*pointer+n` simply returns the first element of the array and adds `n` to it (the result of this is an r-value). `*(pointer+n)` is the n-th element (l-value).

Answer (score 3):

That's quite wrong what you're doing. The dereferencing operator `*` has higher precendence (priority) than `+`, hence `*pointer + n` adds `n` to the value `pointer` points to. Correction:

```
void doubleValuesInArray(int *pointer) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
        int a = *(pointer+n);
        a = a * 2;
        *(pointer+n) = a;
    }
}
```